# import a local model trained

Tags: p5.js, ml5.js

I am in the process of carrying out a small project to learn the alphabet in sign language (and learn p5.js and ml5.js). I got an already [trained model](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/namanmanchanda/american-sign-language-model-99-accuracy) that I want to import into my project. The model was in **.h5** and I converted it with this command:

```
$ tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras model/model.h5 modelJS/
```

When i load the model with load() i get this error: *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load')*

```
let classifier;

function loadModel(){ classifier.load('modelJS/model.json', predict); }

function predict(){ //classifier.classify({image:video},gotResults); }

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480); video = createCapture(VIDEO); video.hide();
  background(0);
  // Load Model
  loadModel()
};

function draw(){ image(video, 0, 0, 640, 480); }
```

Comment: Well, as per this code posted, classifier is undefined. It is declared and not assigned to anything... so it has not a method called load, nor any other thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it, `classifier` is null (`"undefined"`). Therefore it doesn't have the property: `load()`.

In the [ml5js Documentaion](https://learn.ml5js.org/#/tutorials/hello-ml5) `classifier` is set to `ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet')` To use a image classification model:

```
function loadModel(){
    classifier = ml5.imageClassifier('modelJS/model.json');
}
```

Comment: Hello, in documentation there's no _ml5.load_ function. I get this error when I add your answer anyway: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ml5.load is not a function`

Comment: Sorry! I think it is supposed to be `classifier = ml5.imageClassifier('modelJS/model.json');` I'll edit my answer.